# In SQL Server 2012, how to move data from Linked Server to local database

Tags: database, sql-server-2012, automation, linked-server

I am new to setting up data in SQL Server. I have a linked server that is pulling data from Salesforce. I want to pull that data from this linked server into a local database in SQL Server. The size of the tables range from double digit rows to thousands of rows. Is there a way to move every table over to the local database and automatically update the local database with new entries?